# After converting vector data to raster with GDAL in Python, I get completely black TIFF file

Tags: gdal, rasterization

I am trying to convert data from vector to raster with GDAL rasterize using by Python. I want to output raster format as TIFF, but the result TIFF opens completely black.

I am writing code benefit from this recipe: [Convert an OGR File to a Raster](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#convert-an-ogr-file-to-a-raster).

I tried different combinations some part of code but I don't have any solution.

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = 25 # I tried different combinations (0.001 etc.)
NoData_value = -9999

# Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = 'test.shp'

# Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn = 'test.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size)) # I tried different combinations 
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[0]) # I tried different combinations
```

Comment: Hye, welcome to GIS SE. What happens if you add `target_ds = None` at the end of your code?

Comment: What is the burn value that your code is setting?

Answer (score 1):

That [recipe](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#convert-an-ogr-file-to-a-raster) works changed in this way:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

#Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = 25 # I tried different combinations (0.001 etc.)
NoData_value = 0

#Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = 'test.shp'

#Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn = 'test.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
spatialRef = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()

# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)

target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size)) # I tried different combinations 
projection = spatialRef.ExportToWkt()
target_ds.SetProjection(projection)
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1] ) # I tried different combinations

source_ds = None
target_ds = None
```

After running it, I got rasterized vector layer (polygon1) as follows:

[image]